# function application f//x when the function has more than one parameter

Tags: parametric-functions, functional-style

I want to use the function apply (or something even better).

```
x//f
```

with a function that has more than one parameter.
Here is how it works with one parameter.

```
data = Dataset[<|"a" -> <|"x" -> 1, "y" -> 2, "z" -> 3|>, 
   "b" -> <|"x" -> 5, "y" -> 10, "z" -> 7|>|>]
pullz[x_] := x[[All, "z"]]
data // pullz
```

Here is the two parameter version

```
pull[x_, c_] := x[[All, c]]
data // pull
```

Here is the desired result

```
pull[data, "z"]
```

I want to add the parameter "z" to the two parameter version and still use //

Thanks for the help: Here is what I actually used in my code, as learned from the input here

```
r1 = tables // pull[#, "TABLE_NAME"] & // 
  Select[#, StringStartsQ[#, "Patient"] &] &
```

I added the suggestion,  My tables actually comes from the SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM Experiments.INfORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE \
= 'BASE TABLE'
```

Here is the modified Mathematica code

```
pull[c_][x_] := pull[x, c]
tNames = tables // 
  pull["TABLE_NAME] // Select[StringStartsQ[" Patient "]]
```

Comment: `data//pull[#, "z"]&`

Comment: @user6014  I got so close, I tried that but without the &

Comment: Slots (`#`) almost always need a trailing `&` somewhere.

Comment: It is getting closer and closer to r magrittr

Comment: I would suggest you define the operator form `pull[c_][x_] := pull[x,c]`. Then you can write the last line as `r1 = tables // pull["TABLE_NAME"] // Select[StringStartsQ["Patient"]]` (note that both `Select` and `StringStartsQ` also have an operator form). The nice thing about operator forms is that you can omit the `#` & `&` stuff in many cases.

Comment: A roundabout way :) : `data // List // Append@"x" // Apply@pull`

Comment: Related: ["the bullet"](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1634956) and [Curry](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Curry.html)